# How do I select the root node in jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am trying to embed some functionality in my jstree based on whether it is a root node or if it is one of the child nodes.
From the jstree documentation and other Stack Overflow posts that I have gone through, I am now able to populate the items correctly, but I am at a roadblock on how to select the root node of the jstree in an "select_node" condition like the following snippet. Is this correct appending the word "root" to select_node? Please advise. (My root item is called "root", if I have to call get_parent() and check how would I pass my root as paramter). Any pointers to proceed would be appreciated.

```
$(".myjstree").on("select_node.jstree.root", function (e, data){
// do stuff if this is my root node
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listening to `select_node.jstree.root` does not work as intended, as all it does is create an additional namespace for `select_node.jstree` (see the **Event names and namespaces** section from http://api.jquery.com/on/ for more information). `select_node.jstree.root` events are still triggered for all `select_node.jstree` events.

Instead, you can check whether the root node is selected via the `data.selected` property in `select_node.jstree`. You can also interact with it via `$('#jstree').jstree(true).get_node('root')` like so:

```js
$('#jstree').jstree({
  core: {
    data: [
      {
        id: 'root',
        text: 'Root',
        state: { opened: true },
        children: [
          { id: 'child-node-1', text: 'Child 1' },
          { id: 'child-node-2', text: 'Child 2' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
$('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
  if (data.selected.length === 1 && data.selected[0] === 'root') {
    let root_node = $('#jstree').jstree(true).get_node('root');
    console.log(root_node);
  }
});
```

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css";
```

```html
<div id="jstree"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Steve! Your example was of great help.